# pycups debian возвращает ошибку "js: Uncaught (in promise) AttributeError: 'cups.Connection' object has no attribute 'GetDefaultPrinter'"

Tags: python, debian, cups

Всем привет! Пытаюсь распечатать изображение из кода на python при помощи pycups:

```
import cups    

def printImageLinux(image_name):
    conn = cups.Connection()
    printer = conn.GetDefaultPrinter()
    printer.printImage(image_name)
```

После запуска данной функции из кода получаю ошибку:

**js: Uncaught (in promise) AttributeError: 'cups.Connection' object has no attribute 'GetDefaultPrinter'**

Модуль pycups установлен. Служба cups запущена. Принтер установлен и успешно печатает пробную страницу.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Вы уверены, что `cups.Connection` должен иметь метод `GetDefaultPrinter`? В документации он есть?

Comment: @ioprst, пробовал разные варианты, например GetDefault(), результат такой же.

Comment: зачем пробовать разные вариант? Вы документацию смотрели? Я вот не нашел в ней такого метода. Есть `getDefault`, который возвращает строку или `None`.

Comment: @ioprst, Спасибо! Да, вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в использовании несуществующего метода у cups.Connection(). Правильный код будет следующим:

```
import cups

def printImageLinux(image_name):
    conn = cups.Connection()
    printer = conn.getDefault()
    conn.printFile(printer, image_name, 'project_image', {})
```